# Charles proxy internet connection still encrypted

Tags: proxy, charles-proxy

I'm trying to use Charles with my phone but it just doesn't work. I tried with 2 differents phone, an iOS and an android and none of them are working..

Here is the step I followed for iOS : [(I found them here)](https://benoitpasquier.com/charles-ssl-proxy-ios/)

1 - Help > SSL Proxying > Install Charles Root Certificate on a mobile device

2 - On the iPhone, Settings > Wi-Fi > my network > Configure Proxy > Manual And I wrote the IP address and Port that I just got with Charles

3 - I accept the message on Charles that said "a new device is attempting to connect"

4 - Then, on the iPhone, Settings > General > Profiles, I install the Charles Proxy CA

5 - Then, still on the iPhone, Settings > General > About > Certificates, I enable the root certificate

6 - It's supposed to be ready, so I make a test on google and all the contents are still encrypted..

If anyone know how to solve it, I'm listening :)

Answer (score 0):

There are various reasons why you could not intercept the HTTPS Content:

- Your app is using SSL-Pinning, which prevents MiTM apps like Charles Proxy or Proxyman intercepts the HTTPS Traffic. => If it's, there is no way to achive it, unless you have the pinned certificate
- It seems that you tried to see the HTTPS content from google.com, but it doesn't work => Look like one of the steps is missing. Please double-check again.
- If you're testing on Android devices, please make sure you add some config to `network_security_config.xml` file. Read more at https://docs.proxyman.io/debug-devices/android-device#android-setup-guide

**Solution**:

- Follow the [troubleshooting page](https://docs.proxyman.io/troubleshooting/get-ssl-error-from-https-request-and-response#2-solution) to find out where the problem is:
- You might try [Proxyman](https://proxyman.io) - which has a built-in comprehensive guide to help you intercept HTTPS traffic from [iOS](https://docs.proxyman.io/debug-devices/ios-device) or [Android Device](https://docs.proxyman.io/debug-devices/android-device)
- If it's too complicated, you can try the [automatic script for Android Emulators](https://docs.proxyman.io/debug-devices/android-device/automatic-script-for-android-emulator) (Auto set HTTP Proxy, Install and Trust the certificate)

[image: Install Certificate on iOS Device]

Disclaimer: I write Proxyman, and hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

On top of all the steps you mention, you also need to enable SSL proxying.
[image]